# How to bound $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|D_{n}(t)|\,dt$ from above?

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin asked me to bound $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |D_{n}(t)|\,dt$$ from above. I need a bound at the level of $o(\log(n))$.

The background is:

If $s_{n}$ is the $n$-th partial sum of the Pourier series of a function $f\in C(T)$, prove that $$\frac{s_{n}}{\log[n]}\rightarrow 0$$ uniformly. That is, prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|s_{n}|_{\infty}}{\log(n)}=0$$On the other hand, if $\lambda_{n}/\log[n]\rightarrow 0$, prove that there exist an $f\in C^(T)$ such that sequence $s_{n}(f,0)/\lambda_{n}$ is unbounded.

Update: a numerical evaluation for $n=10^{800}$ is inconclusive.

Comment: Is not the integral of the Dirichlet kernel equal to $2\pi $, according to its representation as a trigonometric sum? Or did you mean the integral of $|D_n|$?

Comment: The Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: In its original form it's a [trigonometric sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) in which all nonconstant terms integrate to $0$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ so you are left with $\int_{-\pi}^\pi 1 = 2\pi$.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. I need the absolute value.

Comment: *Be sure to rewrite your question to make this clear*. As for the estimate, my suggestion is to focus on the intervals where $|\sin (n+1/2)t|\ge 1/2$ and use the bound $|\sin t/2|\le t/2$ there. This way you get a sum of integrals of $\int t^{-1}dt$ over a bunch of intervals, which should lead to the desired bound.

Comment: I will rewrite this. Thanks!

Comment: @PavelM: This is Rudin did in his textbook, but his method only showed this up to $\ge C\sum \frac{1}{n}$, which is not enough.

Comment: Think again. Up to a multiplicative constant, there is no waste in restricting to the set where $|\sin (n+1/2)t|>1/2$. There is no waste in $|\sin t/2|\le t/2$ either. From there on, write it out carefully. "$C\sum \frac{1}{n}$" is not being careful. // Also, I checked with the book and it asks $>C \log n$". The notation  $o(\log n)$ means something different. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) but do not overuse this notation where an ordinary inequality can be written just as easily.

Comment: Let me think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelM: for the small $o$ notation; if you let $f=1$ then we need to show $\int |D_{n}|/\log(n)\rightarrow 0$. So this is definitely in the small $o$ scenario.

Comment: And you are calling that "bound from below"? Proving that $\int |D_n|/\log n\to 0$ would amount to showing that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $\int |D_n|\le \epsilon \log n$ for all large $n$. This is a bound from above. (False one, as a matter of fact.)

Comment: I see. I shall update accordingly. But in any case we will not have $>C\log n$ as you commented.

Comment: What edition of Rudin are you looking at? I have 3rd of *Principles*. Page 201. "Problem 21. Let $L_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |D_n(t)|\,dt$. Prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $L_n>C\log n$ for all $n$".

Comment: This is the first edition, the chapter on Banach spaces, page 116. Problem 19.

Comment: OK, this makes things clear. You are referring to *Real and Complex* Rudin. Exercise 19 does not say that $\|D_n\|_1=o(\log n)$; this particular statement is yours, not Rudin's. And, as noted above, a false one.

Comment: What do you mean a false one? This can be deduced from Rudin's statement.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are getting at, but let me working out the bound and see how it is.

Comment: So I tried to verify this numerically. For $n=10^{800}$ the ratio is about 1.57, and it seems with greater $n$ the ratio would keep decreasing. This is inconclusive but I would not claim my statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll replace $|\sin t/2|$ by $|t|$ since they are comparable: 
$$\frac{|t|}{\pi}\le \left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right| \le \frac{|t|}{2} \  \text{ for }t\in [-\pi,\pi]$$
 **Claim:** for all $\lambda\ge 1$ 
$$\frac{1}{3}\log \lambda \le \int_0^\pi \frac{|\sin \lambda t|}{t}\,dt \le \log \lambda +\log \pi +1.$$

*Proof.* For the upper bound, split the integral into "small $t$" part and the rest: 
$$\int_0^{\lambda^{-1}} \frac{|\sin \lambda t|}{t}\,dt
\le \int_0^{\lambda^{-1}} \frac{\lambda t}{t}\,dt =1$$
and 
$$\int_{\lambda^{-1}}^\pi \frac{|\sin \lambda t|}{t}\,dt \le \int_{\lambda^{-1}}^\pi \frac{1}{t}\,dt = \log\lambda + \log \pi$$

The lower bound needs a bit more work. Since the integrand is nonnegative, we can restrict the region of integration to the 
set $|\sin \lambda t|\ge 1/2$. This set contains the intervals $I_k=[\pi \lambda^{-1} (k+1/6),  \pi \lambda^{-1} (k+5/6)]$ for 
all integers $k$ such that $0\le k \le \lambda-1$. The integral over $I_k$ is at least 
$$
\int_{I_k} \frac{1/2}{t}\,dt \ge |I_k| \frac{1/2}{\pi \lambda^{-1} (k+1)} = \frac{1/3}{k+1}
$$
Therefore, the integral is bounded from below by $$\frac13 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \lambda-1\rfloor }\frac{1}{k+1} \ge \frac{1}{3} \log \lambda.$$

---

**Remark.** If $\|D_n\|_{L^1}=o(\log n)$ were true, the estimate in #19 would hold for the Fourier series of any finite measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$. This is not the case. The fact that $s_n$ comes from a continuous function should be used.

Comment: This is not really needed, because Rudin already showed this in his book.

Comment: @user32240 You are welcome.

Comment: But thanks for the help nevertheless; I need to think about the problem myself for a while. Since it is in 3rd edition I assume Rudin must had been serious about it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can get the value of the integral very explicitely. As you already noted
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin[(n+\frac12)t]}{\sin\frac t2}\,dt
= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin\frac t2}\cos\frac t2dt
= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2nt)}{\sin t}2\cos t\,dt\,. $$
Now the fraction can be transformed into
$$ \frac{\sin(2nt)}{\sin t}
= \frac{e^{2nti}-e^{-2nti}}{e^{ti}-e^{-ti}}
= \frac{e^{4nti}-1}{e^{2ti}-1}
= 1+e^{2ti}+e^{4ti}+\cdots+e^{(4n-2)ti} $$
We multiply this with $2\cos t=e^{-ti}+e^{ti}$ and get for the integrand
$$ \frac{\sin(2nt)}{\sin t}2\cos t 
= e^{-ti}+2e^{ti}+2e^{3ti}+\cdots+2e^{(4n-5)ti}+2e^{(4n-3)ti}+e^{(4n-1)ti}. $$
Furthermore, 
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{kti}dt
= \frac2k\sin\frac{k\pi}2, $$
and hence we finally get
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin[(n+\frac12)t]}{\sin\frac t2}\,dt
=2+4-\frac43+\frac45-\frac47\pm\cdots+\frac{4}{4n-3}-\frac{2}{4n-1} $$
which is obviously convergent by the Leibniz criterion and hence bounded by a constant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort - but I have to integral the absolute value instead.

Comment: +1 and please don't delete the answer: combining it with one of my comments, one can get a proof of $\pi = 4-4/3+4/5-4/7+\dots$ which is neat by itself.

Comment: True. Nice. Unfortunately, I need to go now. Maybe I'll solve the problem another time.